# Blocking HTTPS sites through Squid

Tags: https, squid

Can I block https://www.facebook.com through Squid?
It is working very nicely except HTTPS sites
I am using Squid 3.1 in Debian 7

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You should also block it with CONNECT:

```
 acl fb dstdomain .facebook.com
 http_reply_access deny fb
 http_access deny CONNECT fb
```

then:

```
 squid3 -k reconfigure
```

or

```
 squid -k reconfigure
```

Now, it is done!

Comment: Yes I tried and failed. Is there any way to do in transparent mode?