# Squid Proxy blocking HTTPS

Tags: https, proxy, squid

fairly new to squid proxy. Id like to test out blocking HTTPS sites, I've done a fair share of googling, but I don't understand a lot of the solution and the why aspect of it. Can someone help me understand? I'd like to just simply block https://www.facebook.com/ or something for testing purposes. I can easily block any http site or all of them, why is it so much different for HTTPS? I found [Blocking HTTPS sites through Squid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518442/blocking-https-sites-through-squid) but the solution does not work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly does not work for you?  What are you seeing (or not) that you don't like?

Comment: @Adrien I simply can not block any HTTPS sites. Ive watched tutorials and they setup a simple ACL to block something like yahoo.com and it somehow blocks https://www.yahoo.com. In the tutorial the user is essentially using default settings from squid + his acl.

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with squid but I am familiar with proxying.  For https, the browser performs a different kind of request (CONNECT) to set up a tunnel to the server.  Once that tunnel is set up, the proxy is supposed to get out of the way, and the browser sets up a TLS layer with the server.  Typical problems with this, is that the browsers don't show any error information from the proxy in this case (just show generic connection failed UI).  How is the client configured for proxying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the AMI I was using

> Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-da05a4a0

the default squid it was installing could not block https for some reason, I have absolutely no idea why. I switched to using

> Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-6057e21a

and everything now works...If anyone knows why this is the case please let me know.